# What are backpropagation formulas for residual neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am implementing neural network code using C++ so I don’t have access to automatic differentation.

I can calculate gradients/backpropagation for (recurrent) feedforward neural networks easily but have trouble calculating same formulas for residual neural networks (ResNet).

Would somebody point me to online resource which would show step-by-step calculation of gradient/backprop for residual networks (ResNet)?

Comment: You can use $\LaTeX$ formatting to include math typesetting. More information https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference I mention this because people are less likely to follow a link to review a PDF, so your question is more likely to get an answer if it is self-contained.